# What musical instrument does "敫" refer to?

Tags: characters, history

I found the character 敫 whose definition apparently is "ancient musical instrument" according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%95%AB).

However, the English Wikipedia's [List of Chinese musical instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_musical_instruments) doesn't seem to include either it or an instrument whose name includes that character. The closest name (by pinyin) includes "角".

I found a [Baidu Encyclopedia page](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%95%AB) and a [Chinese Wiktionary page](https://zh.m.wiktionary.org/zh-hans/%E6%95%AB), but I can't understand them (and Google translate doesn't help) or the information isn't there.

Does anyone know what instrument or class of instruments "敫" refers to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「敫」 does not have a solid basis for the meaning *ancient musical instrument*, but it looks like that meaning was derived from a transcription or translation error for a word which really did represent an ancient wind instrument. I'll present two interpretations as to where I think this translation originated from, and actually either interpretation arrives at the same conclusion.

---

First interpretation: this is a mistranslation of the [*Shuowen Jiezi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) definition.

> [《說文》：“敫，光景流也。从白，从放，**讀若龠**。”](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=4)
>
> 「敫」: *flowing sunlight*. From semantic 「白」 and semantic 「放」. **Read like 「龠」**.

The *ancient musical instrument* definition is given at [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E6%95%AB), and interprets the last sentence **讀若龠** as imparting both meaning and sound of 「龠」 (original character of 「籥」, as specified [at the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_musical_instruments#Flutes) as a kind of ancient flute), implying that 「敫」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*kleːwɢs/**) is a [rebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle) of 「龠」 (**/*lowɢ/**).

Actually, no such usage of 「敫」 as 「龠」 (籥) seems to be recorded in literature, so **讀若龠** should be interpreted as *having a similar/same sound to* 「龠」 rather than *is a rebus of* 「龠」. I would conclude that Unicode's English definition is wrong.

> **讀若Ｘ** is a bit controversial in its interpretation, so there's probably more misunderstandings in some of Unicode's definitions.

For reference, *Shuowen*'s definition of *flowing sunlight* is a phonetic loan, and its character analysis is incorrect. This definition probably refers to a word cognate to or the same as 「耀」 (**/*lewɢs/**) instead.

<kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state))
石刻
[image]
詛楚文・淵湫</kbd>
　<kbd>[秦朝](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
日書乙種36
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
簡
[image]
[孫臏兵法](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Bin%27s_Art_of_War)
[銀雀山漢簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinqueshan_Han_Slips)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「敫」 is constructed from semantic 「皃」 (*appearance*, here representing *something/someone else*) and semantic 「攴・攵」 (*to hit*), indicating the meaning *to strike/hit something or someone else*. The bottom part of 「皃」 (儿・人) was later corrupted into 「方」.

「敫」 is the original character of 「撽」, and is a similar or the same word as 「敲」.

---

Second interpretation: 「敫」 was misidentified as 「㰾」 during data entry (they kind of look similar), which [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=3C3E) also gives a definition of

> a kind of music instrument in ancient times

Thankfully, this definition has a more solid basis. From [*Zhengzitong*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhengzitong):

> 《正字通》：“今樂器壎箎之屬有㰾子...”
>
> Today (time of authorship of *Zhengzitong*), there are instruments of the type 「壎」 and 「箎」 (ancient wind instruments) called 「㰾子」...

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

Comment: Any idea what a「㰾子」may have looked like?

Comment: @user3306356 㰾 is a phonetic loan for 嘂, which is a large 塤 (variant character of 壎). You can use your imagination from this description: 《爾雅》注曰： ‘燒土為之， 大如鵝子， 銳上平底， 形如稱錘， 六孔， 小者如雞子， 大者曰嘂。 Alternatively, you can Google image search 壎.

Comment: I guess the *Erya annotation* description translates to: *Made from ceramic, as big as a (gosling or goose egg), the top is sharp, the bottom is flat, the shape is like [a counterweight](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%A8%B1%E9%8C%98&rlz=1C1CHWA_enNZ604NZ604&sxsrf=ACYBGNTFZsUj4ub8z668fBKvTR4AmwIFBQ:1580050048536&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs6fqOwaHnAhUXzTgGHS_RBPgQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw&cshid=1580050192041274&biw=1920&bih=937), with six air holes, ...*

Comment: Maybe like an ancient ocarina of sorts?

Comment: In a manner of speaking. "Ocarina" has a lot of different shapes, 塤/壎 certainly isn't just a random shape. If they sound similar, then I guess it is a kind of ocarina (they seem to be classified as the same kind of instrument on Wikipedia)

Comment: https://www.soundofmountain.com/professional-chinese-clay-flute-ancient-xun-instrument-egg-pattern-ocarina-10-holes/ Professional Chinese Clay Flute Ancient Xun Instrument Egg Pattern Ocarina 10 Holes, so maybe: egg ocarina?

Comment: gotcha, egg-shaped clay/ceramic ocarina. nice description

Comment: I think Totoro had one of those & probably Link (i.e.: Zelda) too, although maybe Link's wasn't egg-shaped.

Comment: Thanks! This is all quite interesting!